# Remove file extension in OS X using Terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, osx-mountain-lion

**Problem:**

I have some 200+ files named something in line with "DSC01852.JPG.jpg". I would like to remove the file extension so the result becomes "DSC01852.JPG".

Any suggestions? I looked at the mv command but couldn't quite figure out how to write the correct command.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If these files are all in the same directory you can rename them like this:

```
for f in /some/dir/*.JPG.jpg; do
  mv "$f" "${f%.*}"
done
```

`${f%.*}` removes shortest text matching the pattern `.*` (a dot followed by arbitrary text) from the end of the variable `$f` (in this case the file name), thus producing commands like the following:

```
mv "/some/dir/DSC01852.JPG.jpg" "/some/dir/DSC01852.JPG"
```