# Listing File Names without Extensions in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, rename

I'm using a mac. I need to get a list of files in a folder without their extensions being included in the list. This is because I need a list of products for a website import and conveniently, the image names are the same as the product names. However, my list needs to NOT have the extensions.

I've gotten a list of file names by using terminal and was able to copy them into a text file. Only problem is that the file names include the extension, ".jpg" Using the list I have from terminal, I will now have to go through my text file and manually delete the extension from each file name (there are over a thousand) and this is going to take a long time. Is there an easier way? Can I get terminal to display a list of file names without their extensions so I can copy and paste it into a list? Or can I remove the extensions from these files, then list them in terminal and copy their names? Is there another way? Confused here. I'm not a programmer, just a website design.

Hope someone can help with this. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Borrowed from [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13676108/1928322):

```bash
ls -1 | sed -e 's/\..*$//'
```

I tried flagging as duplicate but didn't work.

One of my own solutions given we know the file extension(s).

```bash
find -type f -exec basename -s '.jpg' "{}" \;
```

So find all files as opposed to directories  `- type f` and then execute `basename` for each. The `-s` allows you to specify a known suffix to remove.

Another alternate solution: [from SU](https://superuser.com/q/597756/370177)

Comment: As the comments on the answer you linked to point out, this removes ***the first*** `.` (and everything to the right of it), so `Mr.Coffee_machine.jpg` becomes `Mr`.  That might be good enough for this OP's needs, but it's a dangerous assumption to make, given that the question doesn't have any example file names, and it's a poor solution to the problem of "removing filename extensions".

Comment: Good point I don't know what the file names are.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your list of files in the file "in.txt", run this script to get the list of files without the extension in "out.txt" :

```
#!/bin/bash    
while read fullfile; do
    filename=$(basename "$fullfile")
    filename="${filename%.*}"
    echo $filename >> out.txt
done <in.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you use `vi` (or `vim`)? 
If you do, then, since you've already got the JPEG file names in a text file,
the easiest way may be to edit that file with `vi` / `vim` and type

```
:%s/\.jpg$//
```

which says, on every line in the file, look for `.jpg` occurring at the end of a line, remove it, and replace it with nothing. 
If there are some lines that don't end with `.jpg`, that's OK;
they will be ignored (skipped over). 
If you've got multiple product names (file names) per line, as in

```
        hammer.jpg              screwdriver.jpg         wrench.jpg
```

just leave out the `$` and add `g` and say

```
:%s/\.jpg//g
```

which will remove *all* occurrences of `.jpg`,
even if they aren't at the end of a line.